# Using the site to create "game guides" and "trophy guides"?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, self-answer

Obviously I'm not talking about about posting an *entire* game guide into one question, that would be way too broad for a question. I'm talking about just general tasks in games that you find semi-difficult or challenging and want to explain to people. According to Jeff, this behavior would be encouraged for any other site, so why not here? Would it be perfectly acceptable to ask a question such as "After *such and such event*, where do I go next?" or "Where do I find *such and such item*?" or "How do I get to *such and such place*?" type questions, then posting a detailed answer of what to do, where to go, etc? How *specific* does the question need to be in order to be considered acceptable?

Also, would a meta tag [game-guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-guide) be appropriate for posts like these?

Then, extend this one step further, would creating trophy guide questions also be acceptable? Should this be limited to *only* trophies which people actually have trouble getting? Should it also get a meta tag [trophy-guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trophy-guide)?

Comment: The meta tag is definitely a no. See [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3704/23). Also check [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30/23) about "question farming" - we definitely don't want that. As for trying to have _all_ the questions - let's focus to answer the _most interesting_ ones; the others will come from outside as needed, if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions asking for help completing an achievement, specific level, or quest are our bread and butter: *most* questions here are of that type. So by all means: definitely ask and answer such questions on Gaming.SE.

With that in mind, [game-guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-guide) and [trophy-guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trophy-guide) would not be good. Nearly every question here would be part of a hypothetical game guide, making the take pretty much meaningless.

In terms of specificity, consider how long answers generally are and what could be captured in one question.

- "How do I kill the boss on level 2A?" is good, "can you walk me through completing Final Fantasy XIII from start to finish?" is bad.
- "What do I need to do to get the X trophy?" is good, "how can I get all 50 trophies in Skyrim?" is bad.

The other end of the scale is being *too* specific. If there's a general question to be made, that'd be more preferable. "Do swords move faster than maces in Skyrim?" is better than "Does X sword move faster than Y mace?", "Does Z sword move faster than A mace?", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In general, questions/answers that are a good fit follow certain patterns:

- The question is one that many people will have. (How do I get this hard trophy?)
- The question is not one with an obvious answer (How do I get the "Kill 10 Monsters" trophy?)
- The question is not easily answerable with 30 seconds on Google.
- The answer is more factual and less subjective ("You have to aim for this non-obvious weak spot on the monster" vs "I think the best weapon to use is the AK47 because you have to reload less often").
- The question has a specific scope. Walkthrough questions would be bad ("How do I find everything and beat the boss in level 3?"), but more specific questions work well ("How do I get on this ledge in level 3?").

Guides and walkthroughs are sometimes awkward fits because they break these patterns. You'd have to take a lot of care to make sure you were sticking to the Q&A nature of the site and less of a dump for GameFaqs content.